# Google autocomplete google.maps.__gjsload__ is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

i'm using google's autocomplete to fill address information on vtiger crm contacts module, using almost he exact same code (changing the ids of html elements) works fine in accounts but in contacts (were it worked for few days), without any changes it doesn't wroks... I have some js error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.\__gjsload__ is not a function(anonymous function) ... places_impl.js

Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.\__gjsload__ is not a function(anonymous function) ... controls.js

Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.\__gjsload__ is not a function(anonymous function) ... utils.js

Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.\__gjsload__ is not a function(anonymous function) ... commons.js
```

Has someone faced this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I was including google's api in other html to use a map... sry